# How to get the value of all the selected option

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a list of dates in an array and I added an option column. What I want to do is get all the selected option of each array and insert it in database when the button "export to excel" is clicked.

When I tried to print all the selected values only the first selected value is the only one that shows.

```
 for ($i=0; $i < count($dates); $i++) { 
     echo " 
              <tr>
                <td>$tripdate[$i]</td>
                <td contenteditable='true'></td>
                <td>$cicuitNumber[$i]</td>
                <td>$triptime[$i]</td>
                <td>$dates[$i]</td>
                <td>$dates1[$i]</td>
                <td>$dates2[$i]</td>
                <td contenteditable='true'> </td> 

    ////////////// OPTION#1 ///////////////////

              <td>           
                 <div class='form-group'>
                   <select class='form-control' id='InterruptionCause' name='InterruptionCause' >
                      <option value ='0' selected>0</option>
                      <option value='001'>001</option>
                      <option value='002'>002</option>
                      <option value='003'>003</option>
                      <option value='004'>004</option>
                   </select>
                </div>
              </td>


  ////////////// OPTION#2 ///////////////////

              <td>
                <div class='form-group'>
                   <select class='form-control' id='InterruptionWeather'>
                     <option value='101'>101</option>
                     <option value='102'>102</option>
                     <option value='103'>103</option>

                  </select>
                </div>
             </td>

   ///////////// OPTION#3 //////////////

             <td>
                <div class='form-group'>
                   <select class='form-control' id='InterruptionDevice'>
                     <option value='201'>201</option>
                     <option value='202'>202</option>
                     <option value='203'>203</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>


  ///////////// OPTION#4 /////////////

            <td>
               <div class='form-group'>
                   <select class='form-control' id='InterruptionEquipment'  >

                      <optionvalue='301'>301</option>
                      <option value='302'>302</option>
                      <option value='303'>303</option>
                      <option value='304'>304</option>
                       <option value='305'>305</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>                     
   </tr>
                        ";

                        }
```

I expect that the output when I export it to database will get all the data including the value of every selected option.

for example:

**[05/31/2019, BT-F4, 14:06:19, 05/31/2019, 14:09:33, 00:03:14, 001, 103, 203, 304]**

**[05/31/2019, CYNSF-F1, 12:44:08, 05/31/2019, 14:46:18, 02:02:10, 003, 102, 201, 302]**

***This is my layout:***

[image: Here's the layout]

Comment: use the array syntax `[]` for the names and remove the ID attributes as an ID must be unique if it exists but you really do not need them here. ie `InterruptionCause[]` for the name - same for other SELECT menus

Comment: Presumably the above table layout is being generated after a call to the database? It would be useful to see that code as it looks like you are missing a trick when it comes to pre-selecting the values selected from the dropdowns - they will always, on each reload, assume the default values as it is currently

Answer (score 0):

Then when form is submitted and you're about to send the information to the database you will have to catch the selected value of your selects objects. You can do it using JQuery calling the selector of the selects (the id as I can see you write it) and call a function that returns the selected value:

```
var selectedValue1 = $('#InterruptionCause').val();
```

You can catch all the selected values at the same time and save it into an array doing this:

```
var arraySelectedValues = $('#InterruptionCause, #InterruptionWeather, #InterruptionDevice, #InterruptionEquipment').val();
```

In order to take all the selected options from all the columns of one kind of select you could maybe add a number (ie `$i`) to have an individual id for every select object. I'll explain my idea with one of the selects. At the moment you're echoing all the selects you have a counter in var $i.

```
 <td>           
     <div class='form-group'>
     <select class='form-control' id='InterruptionCause$i' name='InterruptionCause' >
             <option value ='0' selected>0</option>
             <option value='001'>001</option>
             <option value='002'>002</option>
             <option value='003'>003</option>
             <option value='004'>004</option>
     </select>
     </div>
 </td>
```

You can see that in the id I add the value of the counter making every select individual. In the moment you need to take all the values you just iterate again for every row you have in the table and get every value like this:

```
var listSelectedValues = [];
for(var i=0;i<table.length;i++){
    listSelectedValues.push($('#InterruptionCause'+i).val()); // push() adds an element at the end
}
```

Comment: do I not need to put "[]" in the id? like var selectedValue1 = $('#InterruptionCause[]').val(); ? is it automatic that it'll get all the selected values of the id #InterruptionCause?

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the PHP that generates the HTML by adding a name with the array syntax - remove the ID like below

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($dates); $i++) { 
     echo " 
              <tr>
                <td>$tripdate[$i]</td>
                <td contenteditable='true'>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>$cicuitNumber[$i]</td>
                <td>$triptime[$i]</td>
                <td>$dates[$i]</td>
                <td>$dates1[$i]</td>
                <td>$dates2[$i]</td>
                <td contenteditable='true'>&nbsp;</td>

              <td>           
                 <div class='form-group'>
                   <select class='form-control' name='InterruptionCause[]'>
                      <option value ='0' selected>0
                      <option value='001'>001
                      <option value='002'>002
                      <option value='003'>003
                      <option value='004'>004
                   </select>
                </div>
              </td>

              <td>
                <div class='form-group'>
                   <select class='form-control' name='InterruptionWeather[]'>
                     <option value='101'>101
                     <option value='102'>102
                     <option value='103'>103
                  </select>
                </div>
             </td>

             <td>
                <div class='form-group'>
                   <select class='form-control' name='InterruptionDevice[]'>
                     <option value='201'>201
                     <option value='202'>202
                     <option value='203'>203
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td>
               <div class='form-group'>
                   <select class='form-control' name='InterruptionEquipment[]'>
                      <optionvalue='301'>301
                      <option value='302'>302
                      <option value='303'>303
                      <option value='304'>304
                       <option value='305'>305
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>                     
   </tr>";

}
```

Then you should be able to access each item in the POST array like this:

```
<?php


    $weather=$_POST['InterruptionWeather'];
    $device=$_POST['InterruptionDevice'];
    $kit=$_POST['InterruptionEquipment'];


    foreach( $_POST['InterruptionCause'] as $i => $cause ){
        echo $weather[ $i ], $device[ $i ], $kit[ $i ], '<br />';
    }

?>
```

Comment: do I need a form for this?

Comment: surely you have a form already? If you expect to POST the data anywhere then YES, you need a form. If you simply wish to view data then NO

Comment: What if I also want to print all the data of the row for example: $tripdate. I tried to put name on td : <td name='tripdate1[]'>$tripdate[$i]</td> and the for each would be:  foreach( $_POST['tripdate1'] as $i => $tripdate) but it didn't work

Comment: I can already print the selected values in option. I use form POST